# Previous Visa Refusal/Filed under wrong Category in another country

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I am looking for a tourist visa for UK and whiling filling online application, they are asking whether Visa for any other country was ever refused. 4 years ago, I had applied for US work Visa but I was not issued Visa as Visa officer mentioned that I filed Visa under wrong category. Later on, I revised my application with right category and got my Visa and since then I have been working in USA. Now, question here is, for UK tourist Visa purpose, does it mean I have to say "YES" in the point they ask Visa for any other country was ever refused in last 10 years?

Comment: What did the paperwork for the unsuccessful US visa application say? It sounds as if you should err on the side of caution, answer ‘yes’ and explain the circumstances. Providing the paperwork would also be advisable. Note that the US and UK share immigration data along with the other ‘five eyes’ countries (Australia, New Zealand, and Canada).

Answer (score 2):

Saying yes and explaining what you have written is the safest option and is not expected to have any impact on your new application.